# Is Team Foundation Server (or Azure DevOps Server) compatible with Oracle SSO IAM?

Tags: oracle, tfs, azure-devops, single-sign-on

Is Team Foundation Server 2017/2018 on premises or Azure DevOps Server 2019 on premises compatible with Oracle SSO IAM? In my company we already used Oracle SSO IAM, now we started to use Team Foundation Server 2017 update 1 on premises (we'll update to 2018 or 2019 asap). I'd like to know if TFS 2017 update 1 on premises, or next versions 2018/2019, are compatible with Oracle SSO IAM? Is there any documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

TFS only uses Active Directory authentication (NTLM//Kerberos). You can use a Personal Access Token for some CLI/API actions, but Oracle isn't going to ft into this picture at all.

Comment: If domain is already integrated with SSO/IAM, is possible that TFS uses this integration to obtain single sign on?